# Where can I find missing igraph header files?

Tags: c, igraph, header-files

i have compiled and installed igraph according to the documentation and no errors occurred, additionally i can use and compile the library just fine (I use CLION). No the code completion does not work for *some* of the functions, they seem to be quite basic functions. So I checked if my IDE know the header files installed, located in /usr/local/include/igraph (i use CentOS). It knows them, so i used grep to search through them to find e.g. `igraph_vector_init`, and it is nowhere to be found! No of course I would like the code completion to work and I am at a loss since the appropriate header files do not seem to contain the declarations of often-used functions! Is this a problem with my build? I also checked the online repository, without avail. Additionally I checked that the examples (which use the functions) and the documentation match the version, they do. What could I possibly miss?

Comment: Function `igraph_vector_init` is declared in a header file `igraph_vector_pmt.h` with **using macros**: `DECLDIR int FUNCTION(igraph_vector,init)(TYPE(igraph_vector)* v, long int size);`. Probably, macros are the reason why CLion doesn't autocomplete the function name. I don't know how to overcome this. May be, somehow one can tell CLion to use *precompiled headers* for autocompletion.

Comment: A valuable hint! Thank you for that. I will investigate!